# HTML Classes reference not existing inside document

Tags: html, css

I have noticed that in a lot of HTML pages, that they are referencing classes which don't exist inside the html document. Is this because the classes are referenced from outside the HTML document or are they just hidden somewhere inside the document? Usually you would write classes like this

```
<html>
<style>
.maincontentdiv{some code here}
</style>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably there is a document fragment that is included server-side for all pages, whether the page uses the style or not.

Comment: in most cases classes are defined in external stylesheets - look for something like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css />"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find them in external style sheets.
Your example is an example of an internal style.

Three types of CSS styles:

1 . **Internal style** could be found inside head tag.

```
<style type="text/css">
.class 
{ 
width: 100%; 
}
</style>
```

2 . **Inline style** is placed inside html tags.

```
 <div style="width: 100%;"></div>
```

3 . Best practice are **external styles**. You can link them to your page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css" />
```

Comment: Whilst this information is correct, I'm not sure that it answers the question?

Comment: First  two setences are the answer, aren't they? And the rest is here to explain differences between css styles because if someone asks this question, maybe that would be helpful.

Comment: The OP seems to be stating that they find internal style definitions/selectors in pages that reference HTML classes which are **not** included anywhere on that page - as the selectors are contained within a specific page and *not* a more generic/widely used external stylesheet their point seems to be that it is strange to see them there. Unless I have completely misread what is being asked of course. I'm not sure how your answer resolves that.